# Mongoid does not persist relation between parent and child in this example?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I've been scratching my head on this problem and I can't figure it out. The relation between parent and child isn't saving:

```
class Project
    has_many :project_elements, :autosave => true

    field :name, type: String

class ProjectElement
    belongs_to :project

    field :name, type: String
```

Now I do:

```
    project = Project.new(name: "Project1")
    project.save!

    project_element = ProjectElement.new(name: "Element")
    project_element.project = project
    project_element.save!

    # Test
    test_proj = Project.where(name: "Project1").first
    print test_proj.project_elements.where(name: "Element").first.name
```

This throws the error `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`. Peeking at raw database with mongo shell, the `project_id` doesn't exist on the project element named "Element". The data is otherwise all persisted, just that the relation between `Project` and `ProjectElement` isn't there.

I'm using mongo 2.4.10 and the whatever the latest stable mongoid gem is.

What am I missing?

Comment: I had the same thing and didn't solve it (it seems like a bug). Alternatively you can add èlement` to `product` with `project << project_element` and `project.save`, but probably you are aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I don't exactly know why this doesn't work ( in general ... it's a bug AFAIK ) but to solve this you can use one of the following alternatives

```
project = Project.new(name: "Project1")
project.save!

#solution 1
project_element = ProjectElement.create!(name: "Element", project: project)

#solution 2
project.project_elements.create!(name: 'Element')
```

you can use it the previous solutions with `.new` but remember to save the object after creation as you did in your code samples